# Filtering columns and ranking pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe is -

```
      Metric       Value              Model
0   Accuracy        87.608760       Logistic_Regression
1   Neg_log_loss    -0.332951       Logistic_Regression
2   F1_measure      0.854182        Logistic_Regression
3   AUC             0.927378        Logistic_Regression
4   Precision       0.871396        Logistic_Regression
5   Recall          0.837687        Logistic_Regression
6   Accuracy        96.433245       Random_Forest
7   Neg_log_loss   -0.105780        Random_Forest
8   F1_measure      0.958133        Random_Forest
9   AUC             0.994008        Random_Forest
10  Precision       0.974733        Random_Forest
11  Recall          0.942097        Random_Forest
12  Accuracy        84.836008       Naive_Bayes
13  Neg_log_loss   -0.917701        Naive_Bayes
14  F1_measure      0.823289        Naive_Bayes
15  AUC             0.915744        Naive_Bayes
16  Precision       0.831528        Naive_Bayes
17  Recall          0.815300        Naive_Bayes
```

`metric ='AUC'`

Now I want to select the Model whose Metric column('AUC') is the highest. In this case it will print the model_name `Random_Forest`

Comment: Is your question intended to filter and reorder

Comment: `df[df.Metric=="AUC"].sort_values(by="Value", ascending=False)["Model"].values[0]` it's as simple as just writing code for your requirement

Answer (score 2):

Use, [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) to create a boolean mask, then use this mask along with [`Series.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) to get the `index` of max value in the column `Value` where the metric is `AUC`, finally use this index to get the corresponding `Model`:

```
ind =df.loc[df['Metric'].eq('AUC'), 'Value'].idxmax()
model = df.loc[ind, 'Model']
```

Result:

```
print(model)

'Random_Forest'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```py
df.loc[df.Metric == 'AUC', ['Value', 'Model']].max()['Model']

## -- End pasted text --
Out[1]: 'Random_Forest'
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the other answers, you could also consider grouping your `df` by the `max()` of all `'Metric'` rows:

```
df.groupby(['Metric'], as_index=False)['Value','Model'].max()
```

which you then can also `.query()` for the "AUC" metric's 'Model' column:

```
df.groupby(['Metric'], as_index=False)['Value','Model'].max().query('Metric == "AUC"')['Model']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with the basics then:

```
empty_value_list=[]

for i,j in zip(df['Metric'],df['Value']):
    if i=='AUC':
        empty_value_list.append(j)

max_value=max(empty_value_list)

for i,j,k in zip(df['Metric'],df['Value'],df['Model'])
    if i=='AUC' and j==max_value:
        print(k)
      
Out[1]: 'Random_Forest'
```